# Deploying a meteor app on kubernetes using ssl

Tags: meteor, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

i am new to kubernetes,
just deployed a meteor app on **kubenrnetes** + **gke** -
the app is currently running *not secure*
on a certain IP address.
When coming to secure it and defining a host name for it to run on instead of the ip address ,
that's where i am getting confused...
Can anyone explain and maybe give an example 
what exactly is needed(in pods, srv...)?
and where does nginx come into the story?

Comment: To raise your chance of getting good answers you might want to describe what you already tried and follow the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.